# custom style kendo Vertical Menu Angular?

Tags: angular, kendo-ui

I use the **Kendo UI component** in my current Angular project.

in `Vertical Menu` i can not change the style on some other level (children).

how can I change the style of parents and children of the menu?

Does anybody have some ideas?

> the example link of kendo Vertical Menu:

https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/menus/menu/vertical/

the example of code:

```
   <kendo-menu [items]="items" [vertical]="true" style="display:inline-block; width: 100%;" >
        </kendo-menu>
```

Comment: you can override the styles using `\deep\` but as this was depreciated. So i think you can use view encaptulation in your components.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create `kendo-menu-item` and apply style to it.

```
<kendo-menu (select)="onSelect($event, template)">
     <kendo-menu-item text="Hover me" cssClass="mycustom">
         <kendo-menu-item text="Toggle popup" >
         </kendo-menu-item>
     </kendo-menu-item>
</kendo-menu>

<ng-template #template>
    <p style="margin: 15px;">Hey, it is popup content!</p>
</ng-template>
```

and styles:

```
.mycustom:hover{
  background-color: orange;
}
.mycustom{
  background-color: green;
}
.k-animation-container .k-popup{
  background-color: lightyellow;      
}
```

[Please, see stackblitz example.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tkqkg9-4jcxkr?file=app/app.component.ts)

Comment: I don't know what is this"encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None" but when I add it the end of style it's work well. thanks

Comment: @Aras It is okay. You can read about [encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). If you feel that this answer helps to you, you can upvote or mark it as an answer to simplify the future search of other users. [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)